# How can I read payload of ndef message on windows?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, nfc, msdn

How can I get the payload of NDEF Messages on windows 8?

I has subscribe to receive messages of type T (text messages):

```
MessageType = MyProximeDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF:wkt.T", MessageReceivedHandler);
```

And on my messageHandler I have implemented it:

```
String Message = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf16LE,message.Data);
```

But, when I will receiving a message, she is showed as japaneses (or chineses? u.u) simbols.

Do any you can help me?

(Sorry for my bad english :p )

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm solve my question:

```
 private void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
        {
            try
            {
                IBuffer data = message.Data;
                String strHex = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(data);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 14; i <= strHex.Length - 2; i += 2)
                {
                    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(Int32.Parse(strHex.Substring(i, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));
                }
                MensagemRecebida = sb.ToString();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```